# Does it make sense to talk about absoluteness of concepts, or just formulas? (Soft question)

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, model-theory

Can absoluteness just be an artifact of set theory?

I think most would agree that set theoretic constructions of some objects can be artificial. $\pi$ is a concept for us but the representation of $\pi$ as a set is pretty unnatural (no one would ask "does $x \in \pi$?"). On some level, this isn't really that big of a problem, whatever works works I guess.

But when it comes to absoluteness- absoluteness seems to specifically rely on the exact *formulaic* representation used to define the concept, and not necessarily anything to do with the concept by itself. So is it possible that we may have a concept that we intuitively expect to be absolute, but because of the strange/artificial set theoretic way we construct it, happen to be not absolute? Vice versa is it possible to have a concept we do not think should be absolute, but thanks to some set theoretic contortions we can express it in such a way that makes it absolute (even though that expression is pretty artificial and doesn't really convey the true idea of the concept, like using a set for $\pi$). Does that question make sense?
Or is it too soft to be meaningful?

Comment: What does it mean for a concept to be "absolute"?

Comment: Well-foundedness is a concept that is absolute between transitive models of enough set theory (there are some weak set theories such as KP where this is not the case). At first this is not intuitive at all, but there is a reformulation that allows to see that.